# Facing error in php Illegal string offset

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am writing a code of php that fetch data from dummy json api server.But i am facing this error.

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'employee_name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\jsonapi.php on line 19
name: s

Warning: Illegal string offset 'employee_age' in C:\xampp\htdocs\jsonapi.php on line 21
name: s


Notice: Undefined index: employee_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\jsonapi.php on line 19
name:

Notice: Undefined index: employee_age in C:\xampp\htdocs\jsonapi.php on line 21
name:
```

There is my code.

```
<?php

$api_url = 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees';

// Read JSON file
$json_data = file_get_contents($api_url);

// Decode JSON data into PHP array
$user_data = json_decode($json_data,true);

// Cut long data into small & select only first 10 records
$user_data = array_slice($user_data,0,9);

// Print data if need to debug
//print_r($user_data);

// Traverse array and display user data

foreach ($user_data as $user) {
    echo "name: ".$user['employee_name'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo "name: ".$user['employee_age'];
    echo "<br /> <br />";

}

?>
```

What i should do to remove this kind of error?

Comment: This means `$user_data` contains strings, as opposed to objects.

Comment: what should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [fetched JSON](http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees), the actual data is contained within a `data` field.

So replace:

```
$user_data = json_decode($json_data, true);
```

With:

```
$result = json_decode($json_data, true);
$user_data = $result['data'];
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepthing the answer by clicking the ✔ symbol on the left.